# limitations of install-ubuntu-openstack

Tags: openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot, ubuntu-advantage

I'd like to deploy cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack
on a cluster of 15 8-core blades.
Will the packaged offered for free at:
[Build OpenStack with conjure-up | Download | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)
allow me to expand to 13 worker nodes?

Comment: If you need the three additional nodes to validate a configuration that is significant for your use case, you can contact me privately and I will arrange that for you.

Comment: Jan, if the answer resolves your question, could you please accept it with the checkmark? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Beta of the OpenStack Autopilot can deploy on up to 10 physical nodes before running into the limits of its built-in license.

You may contact Canonical sales to increase the number of managed devices, but this will only become possible after the public beta status for the product ends (we don't like to charge for "beta" functionality).

To be clear, the 10 free nodes will continue to be available even after the Beta period ends.